# How to read HTML content in python from website?

Tags: python, html, pandas

I'm trying to read a table from this nasdaq website https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/quotes/nasdaq-ndx-index but this simple code does not get any result, so I can't understand what I'm doing wrong

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import requests
import time
import random as rd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

def main():
   URL = 'https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/quotes/nasdaq-ndx-index'
   df = pd.read_html(URL)
   print(df)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website generates data in-situ. Instead, read the html from the console using the following code:

```
import requests

headers={"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36"}
result=requests.get("https://api.nasdaq.com/api/quote/list-type/nasdaq100",headers=headers)
print(result)
```

You can find your user agent from your browser. In Google Chrome, right click on the page and click 'inspect'. From here you can go to Network, select a request which contains User Agent information and simply copy and paste.

[image]